# How to call variable in KSH shell script

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script is for checking the status of SSHD2 Number of  connections

CHKOUT="Please also Check the Number of ORPHAN / DEFUNCT Process on `hostname` :"
DFOUT=`/usr/bin/ps -eaf | grep defucnt`
SHCOUNT=`/usr/bin/pgrep sshd2|wc -l`
if [ $SHCOUNT -gt 150 ]

then
    mailx -s "Warning! : `hostname` has more than $SHCOUNT  SSHD2 Connections running Please Check!" karn.kumar@abc.com  << EOF

`echo  $CHKOUT`
`echo "=========================================================="`
`echo  $DFOUT`

EOF
fi
```

======================================

I am unable to get the output of "DFOUT" Variable, Can you guys suggest the correct way of doing this?

```
===================
Edited code that is working nice..

#!/bin/sh
# This script is for checking the status of SSHD2 Number of  connections
CHKOUT="Please also Check the Number of ORPHAN / DEFUNCT Process on `hostname` :"
PS=`/usr/bin/ps -eaf | grep -v grep| grep defunct`
SHNT=`/usr/bin/pgrep ssh|wc -l`

if [ $SHNT -gt 15 ]

then

        mailx -s "Warning!  `hostname` has more than $SHNT SSHD2 Connections running Please Check!"  kk@abc.com   << EOF
        Hi Team,

        $CHKOUT
        ===========================================================
        $PS

EOF
fi
```

Comment: Check your spelling; `grep defucnt`

Comment: `Warning! : Server1 has more than      232  SSHD2 Connections running Please Check!     
Why its taking wider space (double tabs liek) for "than $SHCOUNT" as we see in the above output
`

Answer (score 1):

The issue might have to do with the fact that the echo commands should be writing to the `mailx STDIN` but the way you're doing it with inline backticks might be problematic. I'd try piping the body of the message to `mailx` instead:

```
...
then
    SEP="============================================"
    BODY="$CHKOUT\n$SEP\n$DFOUT"
    echo $BODY | mailx -s "Warning! : ..."
fi
```

Comment: this does not work..

BODY="$CHKOUT\n$SEP\n$DFOUT"
    echo $BODY | mailx -s "Warning! : ...